# Why do return boolean value in this line std::unordered_map<>.insert().second in C++

Tags: c++, boolean, unordered-map, std-pair, insertion

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> url;

url.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("google","www.google.co.kr"));

bool ok = url.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("google","www.google.com")).second;
    std::cout << (ok ? "susses" : "failed") << "\n";
```

This code save short URL and original URL in unordered_map.

In line 3, if I don't use '.second', so this line does not return boolean value.

vscode explain "/@c second is a copy of the second objet".

I want to know what ".second" does and what value it returns.
and why a boolean value is reuturned by typing ".second".

Comment: [`std::unordered_map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) returns a [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).  The `second` member of that pair describes whether or not the insertion took place.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you to read the documentation for [`std::unordered_map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert).

If you look closely, you'll see that when inserting a `value_type` the insert function will return a pair. You can see that `std::unordered_map::value_type` is a pair in the [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) documentation.

That pair contain an iterator and a boolean, to flag if the insertion was done or not.

It can be used like this:

```
auto [iterator, ok] = url.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("google","www.google.com"));
std::cout << (ok ? "susses" : "failed") << "\n";

if (ok) {
    //                       yields google                  yield the address
    //                      v-------------v                  v--------------v
    std::cout << "key: " << iterator->first << " value: " << iterator->second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems like a question that arises from not understanding the return value of insert properly. Now I understand somewhat.

I've read it several times, but I don't think I understand it well because there are still many things I don't know.
Next time I will read more and ask questions.

Comment: @Kwon34 Is there a specific thing I can add to the answer to help you?

Answer (score 0):

The used by you overloaded member function insert is declared like

```
pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& x);
pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type&& x);
```

that is it returns an object of the type `std::pair<iterator, bool>`. It means that the data member second of the pair has the type bool. This data member of the object of the type `std::pair<iterator, bool>` reports whether the insertion was successful.

Pay attention to that in this statement

```
bool ok = url.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("google","www.google.com")).second;
```

you are trying to insert a record with the same key "google" of the previously inserted record in the map.

Here is your code snippet formed as a program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() 
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> url;

    bool ok = url.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("google","www.google.co.kr")).second;
    std::cout << (ok ? "success" : "failed") << "\n";

    ok = url.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("google","www.google.com")).second;
    std::cout << (ok ? "success" : "failed") << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
success
failed
```

Comment: Let's understand the return value of insert again and think more about it. Thank you.